# lftp pause and resume download

Tags: python-2.7, lftp

Googled around and looked on this forum but couldn't find if I can pause a download using lftp.

Currently downloading tons of logs and would like to pause, add more drives to the system and continue downloading.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can either suspend the whole lftp process (command `suspend`) or limit transfer rate to e.g. 1Bps (`set net:limit-total-rate 1`). In either case the files being transferred remain open.
You can also stop the transfer and continue it later using -c option of `get` or `mirror`.

Comment: Is lftp really support continue for mirror? I try `mirror -c <remote_dir>` after interrupt and I have new download (so, my before loaded files are recreated).

Answer (score 1):

In the TUI, Ctrl+Z pauses the command, and `wait` or `fg` resumes it.

```
$ lftp http://192.168.1.22/Backups
lftp :~> mirror 2023-04-24/
[mirroring]
^Z
[0] mirror 2023-04-24/
lftp :~> (do something else)
lftp :~> fg
[mirroring]
```